# Send keyboard info to a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, keyboard

I am trying to get a program to automatically send text at a certain time to another program. I created a short Java code that simulates the program I am trying to use for the actual program. The real-life scenario is I am running a .jar file with a batch file and I want a program that will send keyboard inputs to this cmd window and command the .jar from cmd automatically based on the system time. Any help? I am familiar with AutoIT, Java, and basic batch functions. Thanks!

Comment: check [sendKeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)

Comment: Could you please explain what that does and how to use it? I have an idea of, but I'm not too sure, so as far as I can see, that doesn't really help me.  Also, I don't know JavaScript, I know Java. There's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

play with this:

```
While 1
If @HOUR == 22 And @MIN == 31 And @SEC == 15 Then
    ShellExecute(@WorkingDir & "\example.jar")
    ;Sleep(2000)
    Send("examplecommand {ENTER}")
EndIf
WEnd
```

Comment: Been playing with it. Still hasn't worked. Idk, maybe it's because the java applet wont accept the input, idk. I can type, but that command just won't activate. idk.

Comment: Try Send("{ENTER}") and try it with notepad.exe to make sure it works.